# Error installing node-modules via npm

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

I am trying to install node module redis v0.9.0 locally via npm. I have downloaded the tgz file from https://registry.npmjs.org/redis/-/redis-0.9.0.tgz. Now, when i try to execute the command `npm install redis-0.9.0.tgz`, it is trying to download again from the repository instead of just unpacking and installing. I am trying the command on linux environment. I am not getting why it tries to download.

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/redis-0.9.0.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/redis-0.9.0.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/redis-0.9.0.tgz
npm ERR! Error: DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT
npm ERR!     at SecurePair.<anonymous> (tls.js:1283:32)
npm ERR!     at SecurePair.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
npm ERR!     at SecurePair.maybeInitFinished (tls.js:896:10)
npm ERR!     at CleartextStream.read [as _read] (tls.js:430:15)
npm ERR!     at CleartextStream.Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:320:10)
npm ERR!     at EncryptedStream.write [as _write] (tls.js:344:25)
npm ERR!     at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:219:10)
npm ERR!     at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:209:5)
npm ERR!     at EncryptedStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:180:11)
npm ERR!     at write (_stream_readable.js:573:24)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-220.13.1.el6.x86_64
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "redis-0.9.0.tgz"
npm ERR! cwd /home/abc/download
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.6
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.18
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/abc/download/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to install it in this way:

```
npm install ./redis-0.9.0.tgz
```

Comment: What is the difference that it makes when we use `./`?

Comment: The point that i am not able to understand is previously i was able to install with the command `npm install redis-0.9.0.tgz` and it did not try to download. But now why the same command is not working all of a sudden, instead trying to download. Any idea what could be the possible cause for that?

Comment: If current directory is not added to PATH, you shall refer to the file with ./